# MySQL How do I retrieve ID of LAST_INSERT_ID when using INSERT IGNORE INTO?

Tags: mysql, insert

Scenerio:

1. I'm inserting a CSV file into my database.
2. I'm using jdbc driver to iterate over the file and do the my inserts
3. A `name` column is made `unique` so inserts do not change the table when same value arrives
4. I'm using `INSERT INTO IGNORE` to keep the iteration from breaking when event happens
5. I'm using LAST_INSERT_ID() to add as FK in next table of insert
6. I get 0 when `INSERT_IGNORE` happens

**How do I do fix this?**

```
 Connection con = null;

    try
    {
      Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
      con = DriverManager.getConnection(URL, USERNAME, PASSWORD);
      con.setAutoCommit(false);

      Statement s1 = (Statement) con.createStatement();
      s1.executeUpdate("INSERT IGNORE INTO ORIGIN (ORI_NAME) VALUES(\""
          + d.getOriginName() + "\")");

      Statement s2 = (Statement) con.createStatement();
      s2.executeUpdate("INSERT IGNORE INTO STOCK (ORI_ID,S_TITLE) VALUES ("
          + "(SELECT ORI_ID FROM ORIGIN WHERE ORI_ID =LAST_INSERT_ID()),\""
          + d.getStockTitle() + "\")");

     }

      con.commit();

    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
      if (con != null)
        try
        {
          con.rollback();
        }
        catch (SQLException e1)
        {
          e1.printStackTrace();
        }

      e.printStackTrace();
    }
    finally
    {
      if (con != null)
        try
        {
          con.close();
        }
        catch (SQLException e)
        {
          e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

**Example of CSV file to be inserted into the database**

```
US, P1, M, 200, 344
US, P1, L, 233, 344
US, P2, M, 444, 556
MX, Q4, L, 656, 777
```

Tables:  http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b5752

Comment: What is the problem you're trying to fix? If you are doing "INSERT IGNORE" and the ignore happens, there isn't an insert so there isn't a Last_insert_id for that transaction. If you wanted the previous last insert id, you needed to capture it right after that insert. But for the most recent insert attempt, if it didn't happen, last_insert_id will be 0.

Comment: @DMac well then how do I do an insert into a database when you dont want to replace the existing column when it already exists?

Comment: @stackoverflow I've posted an answer below that suits mysql.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to get an ID for a subsequent insert, your code has to test for a 0 value of LAST_INSERT_ID and if it gets it, do a SELECT on the table to find the right value for the FK for your insert.

In pseudo-code, this would look like:

```
$err = mysql("insert ignore into mytable values ($x, $y)")
if($err){
    do something for an error
}
$id = mysql("select last_insert_id()");
if($id == 0){
    $id = mysql("select id from othertable where condition is true for the record I want to reference in my insert");
    if($id == 0){
        do something for error
    }
}
mysql("insert into othertable VALUES ($id, other stuff)")
```

You'll have to translate that to your own application and language.

Comment: heres my table structure http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b5752 and I will supply an example of the csv file in the above edit

Answer (score 6):

Are you familiar with MySQL's `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` syntax?

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/insert-on-duplicate.html

```
 // Results are the same as doing an update.
 // Note the way the PK can be used to avoid an IGNORE.
 s1.executeUpdate("INSERT INTO ORIGIN (ORI_NAME) VALUES(\""
          + d.getOriginName() + "\" ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE ORI_ID=ORI_ID)");
```

A pratical example here involving the maintenance of failed email addresses for a site:

http://blog.developpez.com/james-poulson/p10016/sql/ne-rien-modifier-en-cas-de-duplicate-key/

As for retrieving the last inserted id the following is taken from the mysql.com link above:

```
Suppose that id is the AUTO_INCREMENT column. To make LAST_INSERT_ID() meaningful for updates, insert rows as follows:

INSERT INTO table (a,b,c) VALUES (1,2,3)
  ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE id=LAST_INSERT_ID(id), c=3;
```

Comment: This should be the accepted answer for sure. Works perfectly and saves a lot of otherwise-required logic for example that which was provided in the accepted answer.